# how to redirect to same domain from http to https

Tags: c#, redirect, https

how to redirect to same domain from http to https in the application_beginrequest event in a class file complied as dll using c#.

i cant redirect to the same server... any suggestion...

Comment: Why not do it in the IIS settings? (For iIS 7/7.5 this would be in the `web.config`.)

Comment: @Richard Can the answer of Ardman be done in web.config? And how?

Comment: @Lieven: Yes, go through it in the UI, and see what changes it makes to the `web.config` file (if done at a global level it'll be in the global web.config of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
//Check if page is running under https. If not redirect to secure page...
if ((!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://" + Context.Request.Url.Host + Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Request.Url.ToString.ToLower.StartsWith("http://")) {
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString.Replace("http://", "https://"));
}
```